# navigator controller AND tabbar controller at the same time?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using the `UITabBarController` to control the views and just want the `UINavigationController` so I can show the title in it (as well as show a "Save" button.

Is it possible to have both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576604/how-to-used-navigation-controller-and-tab-bar-controller-in-appdelegate-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having both is perfectly possible. The natural thing to do would be to have a UITabBarController load first, and have each `UIViewController` it loads upon tab selection be an instance of `UINavigationController`. In fact, I have just done the very same thing using this tutorial: http://blog.willwinder.com/2011/05/xcode4-uitabbarcontroller-with.html

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Apple's docs cover this well. Check out the [View Controller Progamming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457). Basically you add UINavigationControllers to the UITabBarController. Each UINavigationController is initialized with the desired UIViewController as its rootViewController.

Answer (score 1):

first add the navigation controller to tabbarcontroller's rootviewcontroller
 and than add the tabbarcontroller as window's subview